# Handling Effective Dated records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table structure with data:

```
EFFT_DT|TYPE|CODE|VALUE
```

For instance, these can be the data records:

```
EFFT_DT    |TYPE  |CODE|VALUE
------------------------------
01-APR-2014|TYPE_A|01  |Apple
01-APR-2014|TYPE_A|02  |Pear
01-APR-2015|TYPE_A|02  |Orange
01-APR-2016|TYPE_B|A   |OTHERS
01-APR-2012|TYPE_B|B   |Tropical Fruits
```

Problem: I need to be able to query the records in this table and retrieve the latest effective dated record by passing in a) a date b) a code to retrieve the VALUE.

For instance, I could pass in a) 15-apr-2014 b) 02 and compare the EFFTDT and CODE to retrieve Pear. I could also pass in a) 20-apr-2015 b) 02 and compare the EFFTDT and CODE to retrieve Orange. This means the as of 15-apr-2014, the 1st record is tagged to Pear and subsequently changed to Orange.

I could also pass in a record with a)01-apr-2012 b) B and 02 and be tagged to Tropical Fruits first before eventually being tagged Pear or Orange subsequently when another date records are passed in.

High Level: I am thinking to query based on the params for type_A first to retrieve the VALUE and check if it's null, if NULL, query for type_B to retrieve VALUE.

Are there any other ways to go about doing this?

Appreciated!

Comment: When you say latest effective dated, does it always have to be lower than the passed parameter date ? Or it can be higher as well in your requirement ?

Comment: May be you can just declare a function, that would return `ROWID` of the record that you need to select. This function willbe called in the `WHERE` clause of your query, something like `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ROWID = Function_name(param_date, param_code);`. This function will have logic in it, to determine which one of the parameters have been passed (or just include both in the `WHERE` clause, which would select from the table. You can have the whole logic in a single function and call it in a `SELECT` statement, or just embed the `IN` values in the `WHERE`. Wouldn't that solve it for you?

Comment: @pOrinG - It can be higher as well for the passed date param. Something like MAX(EFFT_DT)<= <passed_date_param>